# What happens if a wizard uses a spell against a monster that is immune to it?

Tags: dungeon

In Dungeon! a wizard must choose to use a spell, let's say lightning, **before** the monster of a room is revealed. What happens if the monster is revealed and it appears to be immune to lightning, as shown by the "-" sign?

Answer (score 2):

It is treated the same as if they rolled a number that was too low.  They are defeated and suffer the usual consequences.

There are various different versions of the rules.  The ones [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/nmi11vs0k/New_Dungeon_Rules.pdf) show it on page 10, third paragraph.

Comment: Are you sure, do you have any reference to the rules for this? It seems strange because using a spell means that the monster cannot retaliate, so if the spell fizzles because of the immunity then in fact nothing would really happen. I wonder if the wizard would loose the spell card then?

Comment: You are correct that a wizard takes no damage when failing with a spell, but still loses the spell.  There are - monsters for things other than spells though too.

Comment: Your link seems dead. Mind updating it?

Comment: Its a PDF, so it probably won't work on phones and such.  Sorry, I don't know of a better location to link to the rules.  I got it from http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/3102/new-dungeon-rules-pdf

Comment: Is "**New** Dungeon" the same thing as "Dungeon!"?

Comment: It wasn't just a mobile issue; it appears BGG files use a different-than-normal download system. I updated the link to the pdf on BGG; seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

In *WOTC*'s Dungeon!, [the rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20170405010950/http://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/Dungeon%21_Rulebook.pdf) imply that, if a monster is immune to the spell, the spell simply fizzles.

However, they also state that "Each Monster card includes icons for the Fireball and Lightning Bolt Spells," so theoretically no Monsters are immune in this edition.